# Creating a Mathematical Model for an Elevator

Tags: pr.probability

This is a problem I have been thinking about for a while.

Everyday, I take an elevator and observe that people get on and off. Given the current situation (i.e. what floor I am on and how many people are currently in the elevator) - I find myself always trying to guess:

- When the elevator will reach my destination?
- What floor will the elevator stop on next?
- How many people will enter and exit the elevator on the next stop?

While I wait in the elevator, I always think: Suppose if we had an entire elevator log that detailed every elevator trip that was made over a year , and this included information how many people got on/off at each floor: How could we create a mathematical model to represent this system and answer the above questions?

To begin, let's state some of the following conditions:

- The elevator has a maximum capacity of $n_k$ people : once $n_k$ people have entered the elevator, no one outside the elevator can request the elevator to stop. The elevator can only stop when someone inside requests the elevator to stop or once the elevator has reached the final floor.
- When the elevator starts, there are currently $n_0$ people on the elevator (where $n_0$ is some positive integer)
- There are $m$ floors in total
- On the $j^{th}$ floor (where $ j\leq m$) , the number of people that enter can be denoted by $x_j$ and the number of people that exit can be denoted by $y_j$
- **The immediate future of the elevator is only decided by the current situation of the elevator** (i.e. what floor we are on and how many people are in the elevator) - i.e. **the elevator has the memoryless property**
- The time of day does is not being taken into consideration and is being considered as irrelevant in this problem (i.e. peak hours like lunch break, end of day, etc. are not important).

The first thing that comes to mind is to use (Discrete Time) Markov Chains. As such, I think the elevator can be thought of to contain two underlying Markov Chains:

- Markov Chain for Floor Transitions: A Markov Chain can be created which will look at the probability of the elevator stopping at any other floor given the current floor
- Markov Chain for Elevator Capacity: A Markov Chain (similar to a queue/birth-death process) can be created which will look at the net change in capacity given the current capacity

**My Question:** **Given access to the elevator log - I know how to create two independent Markov Chains to model floor transitions and elevator capacity independently.**

- Using conditional probabilities, I could analyze the number of times the elevator was on the $i^{th}$ floor - and of those times, how many times was the next stop made at the $i^{th}$ floor: this information would serve as an estimate of $p_{i,j}$, the probability of directly transitioning from the $i^{th}$ floor to the $j^{th}$ floor (note that $p_{j,i}$ does not need to be equal to $p_{i,j}$).
- Using conditional probabilities, I could also analyze the probability of the change in capacity. If the elevator current has 5 people - I could calculate what is the probability that after the next stop, there will now be 9 people.

**But it is unclear to me how to "jointly" model both of these Markov Chains together.**  For example, if the elevator reaches capacity at the 3rd last floor - it might be very likely that no one will request a stop until the final stop. However, if the elevator reaches maximum capacity early on - it might be more likely that someone on the elevator will have to go to an intermediate floor and give the elevator another chance to start accepting more passengers and take on more possible trajectories.

**I thought perhaps I could combine both of these chains together into a single chain - but the number of states in this single chain would explode in size**, for example:

- State 1: 1st Floor, 0 People
- State 2: 1st Floor, 1 Person
- State 3: 1st Floor, 2 people
- State 4: 1st Floor, 3 people
- ...
- State 1-k: 1st Floor, $n_k$ people
- ...
- State k-m:$n_k$ people,  $m^{th}$ floor

**Apart from resulting in a very large number states and make all computations difficult - more concerning would be the fact that I might not have enough data (i.e. joint combinations of floor transitions at varying capacity levels) to reliably estimate all state probabilities**

**Can someone please advise me on how I can use Markov Chains to jointly model both of these processes (i.e. floor transitions and capacity)?**

Thanks!

Comment: Essentially the same question (with bounty) at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731910/how-to-create-a-mathematical-model-of-an-elevator